# $R^nf_*\mathbb{Z}$ trivial for a morphism with hypersurface fibers.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I have some questions on local systems. If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of projective complex algebraic varieties, $Y$ being a curve, I want to prove that if the fibers of $f$ are smooth hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$ then $R^nf_*\mathbb{Z}$ is a trivial localy system, isomorphic to the constant sheaf $\mathbb Z$. But I have no clue why such an assertion might be true.

The only thing I can think of would be to base change to $U$, an open set in the curve, such that U is in the smooth locus of f, there I could use that if I take U sufficiently small, the f is a fibration, and compute the cohomology $H^n(U, \mathbb Z)$. But firstly I dont see how that helps. And in anycase I miss the place where $f$ is not smooth.
Could somebody help me?

Comment: To attract more attention, it might be helpful to change the title into something rather more specific.

Comment: Thanks I've changed it to something hopefully more specific.

Comment: @floflo You say that $f$ has smooth fibres. In particular, assuming $X$ is integral and $Y$ is a smooth curve, then $f$ is flat so that $f$ is a smooth morphism.  Therefore $U=Y$ in your second paragraph. Also, a local system being trivial usually means it's zero. In any case, what you claim is not true if $n$ is odd. I tried explaining this in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $n\geq 3$ below.

The morphism $f:X\to Y$ in your question is a smooth projective family of $n-1$-dimensional hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$. (You say in your first paragraph that the fibers are **smooth** hypersurfaces.)

The cohomology of a single hypersurface of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb P^n$ in degree $\neq n$ is quite simple to compute by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. Indeed, if $F$ is a smooth $n-1$-dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ (with $n\geq 3$) then the following holds.

If $i$ is even and $i\neq n-1$, then $H^i(X,\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$.
If $i$ is odd and $i\neq n-1$, then $H^i(X,\mathbb Z) = 0$.

So if $n$ is even, then the cohomology of the fibers of $f$ is $\mathbb Z$. This then implies that $R^n f_\ast \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$ (by some arguments I omit for now).

If $n$ is odd, then the cohomology of the fibers of $f$ is $0$. Therefore, $R^n f_\ast \mathbb Z = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much answers my question and I kinda see how this goes now. Concerning the arguments you omit, would that be the semi continuity theorem? 
As for computing the cohomology of a hypersurface using lefshetz hyperplan theorem. I'm gussing that you do this by induction taking a smooth hyperplane section, I need to write down the details.